# Nested functions in C?

Tags: c++, c

can any one tell me can we declare a function in user defined function ? such as

```
int sum(int x, int y)
{
    int fun( float x);
}
```

Can we define a function inside a function ? As I know we can't define a function inside a function.

But I just did this and its work fine the code is given below :

```
{
    int main()
    { 
        func1();
        return 0;
    }
    func1()
    {
        int i = 0;
        auto func2()
        {
            i = 10;
            printf("Heloo i am func 2\n");
        }
        printf("Heloo i am func 1\n");
        func2();
    }
}
```

It works very fine .

Now can anyone tell me what is going around how a function inside a function is defined or working properly ?

Can anybody explain to me why the code is working ?

Now when I changed few lines of code it give me following problems
The changes are following:

code:

```
{
    func1()
    {
        func2();
        int i = 0;
        auto func2()
        {
            i = 10;
            printf("Heloo i am func 2\n");
        }
        printf("Heloo i am func 1\n");
    }
```

error:

```
error: static declaration of ‘func2’ follows non-static declaration
note: previous implicit declaration of ‘func2’ was here
```

Now what are these error and why are they coming ?

If I call `func2()` in `main` function than it will show an error like
`undefined reference to func2`

Now can anyone tell me what is wrong here ?

Comment: way too many question marks...

Comment: It should be noted that whether this is allowed or not is just a language nerd curiousity. In real-world applications, you will never write declarations nor definitions inside other functions.

Answer (score 2):

The C standard allows the *declaration* of functions within functions (as in your first code snippet), but not the *definition* of functions within functions (although some compilers may offer it as a non-standard extension).

The same is true for C++, although newer versions (C++0x, etc.) allow you to define anonymous lambda functions.  But this is something different.

Comment: what is different i want to know that .why the code is executing ?

Comment: @user: Presumably you're building with a compiler that supports nested functions.  And presumably it requires that the function is declared *before* it is invoked (this is certainly true for "standard" non-nested functions).  This isn't the case in your code snippet that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[gcc allows this in C only (not C++)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html) via `-fnested-functions`, but this is of course non-standard and non-portable so you should probably not use nested functions unless you have a very good reason.

Comment: pal what about the error when i call the func2 before its definition

Answer (score 0):

This, for `foo`,

```
int main(void) {
    int foo(void);
}
```

is not a definition of `foo`. It is a **declaration** and it is perfectly valid *(though strange: function declarations belong outside any other functions)* in `C`.

What `C` does not allow, which is what you found out, is that **definitions** cannot be nested.

```
/* INAVLID EXAMPLE */
int main(void) {
    int foo(void) { return 0; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `func2()` before declaration, C assumes (according to standard) implicit declaration `int func2(...)`, but when compiler finds `func2()` definition, it differs from previous implicit declaration, so compiler complains about it.
If `func2()` precedes the call to `func2()`, it acts as both definition and declaration, so no problem there.

And of course `func2()` cannot be called from `main()` as its scope is limited to `func1()`, like you cannot access local variable from another function.

As others mentioned, nested functions aren't standard in C, although some compilers (like GCC) support this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a supplement to *Paul R*'s answer.
Assuming that your compiler is GCC,
the end of the
[document](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html)
in *Paul*'s answer says:

> A nested function always has no
>   linkage. Declaring one with `extern`
>   or `static` is erroneous. If you need
>   to declare the nested function before
>   its definition, use `auto`

So `func2` has to be declared as `auto` before the call of it.
If you change the second code

```
func1()
{
    func2();
    int i = 0;
    ...
```

to

```
func1()
{
    auto func2(); /* declaration added */
    func2();
    int i = 0;
    ...
```

the code will be compiled.